# Clicking on RecyclerView item change its style

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

As title says I want to change RecyclerView item style when I click on button inside it or on RecyclerView item (not on all items just on clicked one). 
It should look like

[image]

After any of buttons are clicked hide transparent overlay and do the action on that item

Comment: ok put your code to check the problem

Comment: I did not write any code for that yet. I just have code for layout behind and it works good

Answer (score 1):

Hello i did something similiar, i had a recyclerview and i needed the background to change when an item was clicked, what i did is this:
In the ViewHolder constructor i added a simple `OnClickListener`:

```
public NoteViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (view.isSelected())
                    view.setSelected(false);
                else
                    view.setSelected(true);

                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked!");
            }
        });
    }
```

At this point the state of you item will be toggled between selected and un-selected state. Now you can add a selector for the background, in my case the recycler item layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="nome"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="@drawable/selected_background"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
/>
```

While selected_background is...well a selector! Here it is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/selected"/>
</selector>
```

When the item is in selected state the background will be changed to the one specified in the "selected" color, or you could pass a drawable, image etc...

At the same time you set the selected state on one item you could unselect the others.

Hope it helps.